# Assemble.io escape html file from partials

Tags: assemble

I want to include partials template as escaped HTML (to use inside of `<pre><code>...<code><pre>`).

I'm trying some `{{md}}` and `{{embed}}` helpers, but without success.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've read the question correctly, but have you tried using 3 curly braces eg:

```
{{{text}}}
```

To escape your HTML and

```
{{> partial }}
```

to include your partial on the page.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, had to use {{{md "readme.md"}}} - Thank you!